# Trying to remove vector pointer duplicates. Why can't I use .erase()?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector, iterator

I've got a vector of pointers for my "Faction" class, stored in such a way:

```
vector<Faction *> factionptr_;
```

At this point, I am already able to sort my vector in alphabetical order, so I figured I could use this code here to remove any duplicates that'd show up next to each other:

```
void Faction::deleteDuplicateFaction(vector<Faction *> &factionptr_){

 for (int i = 0; i < factionptr_.size()-1; i++){

      if (factionptr_[i]->getFactionname() == factionptr_[i + 1]->getFactionname()){
            cout << "it's the same" << endl;

            factionptr_.erase(factionptr(i));
      }
```

But I'm getting an error at .erase() and I don't understand:

```
    IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::erase [with _Ty=Faction *, _Alloc=std::allocator<Faction *>]" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (Faction *)
        object type is: std::vector<Faction *, std::allocator<Faction *>>
```

Now I understand that I could be using iterators for this, but I'm not too familiar with them yet. I am definitely not averse to a solution involving iterators though.

Perhaps there's another way?

factionptr is this:

```
Faction * Faction::factionptr(int k) const{
 if ((k < 0) or(k > numberOfFactions())) // elementary error checking
      return NULL;

 return factionptr_[k]; // returns a pointer to the k-th daughter
```

}

Comment: `factionptr_` != `factionptr`

Comment: What's `factionptr` ?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < factionptr_.size()-1; i++) seems to be wrong if you want an iteration over entire loop use i < vector.size().

Comment: @WhozCraig No, that's fine, it's just one of my methods so I'm not referencing the memory location.

Comment: @AlexanderVX it's also a disaster in the making if the vector is empty.

Comment: You seem to be looking for `std::unique` with a custom predicate, followed by `erase` a la the erase-remove idiom.

Comment: Are you familiar with iterators?

Comment: @imgoingmad Mind putting that in your post ?

Comment: Related: *please* tell us `factionptr(i)` isn't simply equivalent to `return factionptr_[i];` Better-still, *post it*. Better-than-better-still, post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @n.m. I know them just little, only ever used them a couple of times.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, it's the same, wanted to use it in main earlier. doesn't make a difference besides readability and systematic-ness. I'll change it now.

Comment: You don't need that function for this task, and you certainly don't need a parameter that seems to be hiding your member variable name.  There is indeed a better way to do this (see [T.C's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30553687/1322972)), and I sincerely hope the pointers are not the only referals to those objects; they'll leak if they are.

Comment: @WhozCraig About the empty vector thing, I'm not sure I understand.  I'm specifically referencing elements using pointers because I'm trying not to create an actual vector. The pointers are created from an input file, and I'm able to list the out all nicely. By the end of things, I'm hoping to make a list of these pointers as nodes. Sorry, I'm just a little confused.

Comment: If the vector were empty, then `size()-1` will probably not do what you think it will. `size()` returns an *unsigned* integer type. [See example here](http://ideone.com/ZcX9yY). And if those are the *only* pointers that refer to those `Faction` objects, this (your code or TC's) will leak those objects. It would be better to not use pointers at all unless you're doing this for polymorphic reasons, and in that regard use smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`. Anyway, best of luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wheel reinvention should be discouraged. This is [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) with a simple custom predicate followed by an `erase`.

```
auto pred = [](Faction* a, Faction* b) { 
                return a->getFactionname() == b->getFactionname(); 
            };
factionptr_.erase(std::unique(factionptr_.begin(), factionptr_.end(), pred),
                  factionptr_.end());
```

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks, I had it initially, somehow got lost during formatting :)

Comment: No worries. I was about to post the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, T.C. This works. Thanks everyone else who helped too. Just gonna go try to understand what's going on here.

Comment: @imgoingmad spend some time perusing [some documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique). And note that site is *fantastic* as a general reference, so put it on your bookmark bar.

Answer (score 0):

`vector::erase` does not take a value for its parameter, it only takes an iterator (or a pair of iterators).
In your case, as you have a index value (`i`), you can get the right iterator this way:

```
factionptr_.erase(factionptr_begin()+i);
```

Note that this will change the length and content of your array, so your loop will not work as expected. One way around this is to only increment the `i` value when you *don't* erase an element.

```
for (int i = 0; i < factionptr_.size()-1){

     if (factionptr(i)->getFactionname() == factionptr(i + 1)->getFactionname()){
           cout << "it's the same" << endl;

           factionptr_.erase(factionptr_begin()+i);
     }
     else {
           i++;
     }
}
```

Also take note of whoiscraig's comment about what happens with an empty vector.